# JRE installation fails in mac os 10.8

Tags: java, macos

After deleting all Java installations (multiple Java versions were present) in my Mac from

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/

any new installation of JRE fails with following exception (from /var/log/install.log)

```
Jan 16 13:28:51 MacBook-LT installd[1171]: ./postinstall: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Jan 16 13:28:51 MacBook-LT installd[1171]: ./postinstall: java.lang.NullPointerException
Jan 16 13:28:51 MacBook-LT installd[1171]: ./postinstall: at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:514)
Jan 16 13:28:51 MacBook-LT installd[1171]: ./postinstall: at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
Jan 16 13:28:51 MacBook-LT installd[1171]: ./postinstall: at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1119)
```

How to recover from this error?

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I reinstalled the OS.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing the same.

Comment: @avis that's an extreme solution! did you try installing Java using `Homebrew` & `homebrew-cask`? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252591/mac-os-x-and-multiple-java-versions/29195815#29195815